# Cocos2d facebook - How to Update Satus from cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to update status from cocos2d code for that i download sdk but i don't know where to start ? Please let me know how can i update status from cocos2d and which library i have to use ?

Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with cocos2d, so a general search on facebook integration should be fine. Adding cocos2d to your google search will just limit your results.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Hackbook demo from the [developer.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) website to start with the simple Facebook demos. And you can move with the Cocos2d and FaceBook integration to complete the stuff you need.